# Environment Variables disappearing after clicking apply in IntelliJ

Tags: java, variables, testing, intellij-idea

As the title says, when I enter my environment variables into intelliJ - once I hit apply, OK and reopen the application the variables are not there anymoer. I have tried creating a new application each time, rebuilt my entire project and recloned repository (just in case). Iv done everything except reinstall intelliJ as I work on a strict network where I dont have many admin rights.

[With varaibles added -(not actual hostname)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC1u4.png)

[After clicking apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkSVd.png)

I have no idea why this is happening and either does anyone in work but I cannot run application services anymore until this is fixed as I need to use my hostname. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can see this : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000211939-Default-Run-Debug-Configuration-values-has-gone-away

Comment: Just tried this - reimported project again. Still the same issue after creating new application and selecting apply. Thank you though